# Il faut bien sauver ce qui peut l'être

Tags: infinitif, participe-passé, pronoms-personnels

*Paris-Briançon* de Philippe Besson :

> C'est un quai, noirci par la pollution et les années, où un
> échafaudage a été installé parce qu'il faut bien **sauver** ce qui
> peut **l**'être, et où des voyageurs pressent le pas, sans prêter
> attention à la verrière métallique qui filtre les derniers rayons du
> soleil.

*L'être* signifierait ici *être sauvé*, donc je ne comprends pas pourquoi l'auteur l'utilise, car *sauver* et *sauvé* ne sont pas exactement les mêmes mots.

Comment: En effet, c'est un construction qui signifie _"il faut bien sauver ce qui peut être sauvé"_. Et pour ne pas apporter la lourdeur de répétition de _"... sauver ... sauvé ..."_ on utilise _"ce qui peut l'être"_.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Mais _sauvé_ n'est pas exactement le même mot si on le compare à _sauver_.

Comment: C'est le même verbe, l'un utilisé à la forme activer: _sauver_ et l'un a la forme passive _être sauvé_.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Je voulais dire pas la même forme du même verbe. Mais quoi qu'il en soit, je vois qu'il est possible de le faire.

Answer (score 2):

Le principe qui explique cette apparente anomalie se trouve à la section « **653** »  de *Le Bon Usage* (édition 14).

> **§ 653**  « Accord » du pronom.
> **c)** **Lorsque l'antécédent est autre chose qu'un nom ou un autre pronom**, le pronom ne garde aucune marque de l'antécédent et il est considéré comme neutre (ce qui se traduit par le masculin singulier, c'est-à-dire par le genre et le nombre indifférenciés).
> Si on remplaçait le pronom par le mot adéquat, celui-ci n'aurait
> pas nécessairement la forme de l'antécédent :
> ♦ Elle demeura tout interdite ; je L'étais beaucoup moi-même [dit Adolphe]
> (B. CONSTANT, Ad., II) [C = interdit, et non interdite ; cf. § 673, b],
> ♦ Cela permet de ne pas punir ce qui ne doit pas L'être (MONTHERL., Équinoxe de sep-
> tembre, p. 265) [f = puni, et non punir ; cf. § 673, c], — Autres ex. au § 671, ».